# Left join two values in one row

Tags: php, mysql

Table `matches` has the following columns:

```
id, teamA, teamB
```

Table `teams` contains:

```
id, name
```

I want to output both of the teams, and managed to do it with this:

```
$sql1 = SELECT teams.name FROM matches LEFT JOIN teams ON matches.teamA = teams.id
$sql2 = SELECT teams.name FROM matches LEFT JOIN teams ON matches.teamb = teams.id
```

Then I output it with a while loop:

```
echo $sql1->name, $sql2->name
```

The problem I had when trying one query was, that the team name could only be output once per row.

How would this work with one query?

Comment: `SELECT team1.name as team1, team2.name as team2  FROM matches LEFT JOIN teams team1 ON matches.teamA = teams1.id LEFT JOIN teams team2 ON matches.teamB = teams2.id`

Comment: I dont have a table "team1", i only have "teams". `SELECT team1.name as team1` would not work.

Comment: No need to be mean. The simple explanation suffices.

Comment: I already ran the query before my answer, it returned nothing. Also you are writing `SELECT team1.name as team`

Comment: Isnt the team1.name requesting the name from table "team1" and then setting it to the alias "team1"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT team1.name as team1name, // Select the first team name from the table aliased as team1, aliasing that column as team1
       team2.name as team2name  // Select the second team name from the table aliased as team2, aliasing that column as team2
  FROM matches
  LEFT JOIN teams team1         // Alias our first join to teams on teamA as team1
    ON matches.teamA = team1.id
  LEFT JOIN teams team2         // Alias our second join to teams on teamB as team2
    ON matches.teamB = teams2.id
```

When you execute this query, you should get 2 team names returned, one aliased as `team1name`, the other as `team2name`; so when you retrieve these to your PHP, they will have those aliased column names

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/80d580/1)

Comment: Found the mistake: `ON matches.teamA = teams1.id` should be `team1.id`.

Comment: Why don't you actually try it, or go look at my demo

Comment: Its working and i understand all except `SELECT team1.name`. Why "team1" here before the point. What is it doing really? Shouldnt it be the table name?... I'm quite confused.

Comment: No, it can't be the table name, because we have 2 left joins against the same `teams` table, and SQL wouldn't otherwise now which of the two we were referring to.... that's why we alias the joins, and use the alias to reference the column name

Comment: I might be confusing you by using the same column aliases as table aliases, I've modified my answer accordingly

Comment: Now i understand it, the first LEFT JOIN is team1 and the second is alias'd  as team2. I didnt know that was possible. Thanks for your insight, time and patience!